# Initiate Mail From Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button click event in jquery, Inside which I want to initiate my mailbox on it's click with a particular text as the mail's body that is stored in a variable.

Following is my code:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){

         $('#btnLaunchEmail').hide();
         if (strExternalZippedLink.trim() != '') {
             //Here I have to initiate the email
         }

})
```

I tried a lot of things but didn't worked . Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below code:

```
   if (strExternalZippedLink.trim() != '') {

                //Lunching the email
                var aLink = document.createElement('a');
                aLink.href = 'mailto:?body=' + strExternalZippedLink;
                aLink.click();
            }
```

strExternalZippedLink will be shown in the body

Comment: Am glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `mailto` URL. Wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){

         $('#btnLaunchEmail').hide();
         if (strExternalZippedLink.trim() != '') {
             var to = "someone@example.com";
             var subject = "This is my subject";
             var myBody = "This is the message body";

             window.location = "mailto:" + to +"?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + myBody;
         }

})
```